# Allocate memory to a process that other process can not use in linux

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, ulimit, cgroups

To limit memory resource for particular process we can use ulimit as well as cgroup.

I want to understand that if using cgroup, I have allocated say ~700 MB of memory to process A, on system having 1 GB of RAM, and some other process say B, requires ~400 MB of memory. What will happen in this case?

1. If process A is allocated ~750 MB of memory but using only 200 MB of memory, will process B can use memory that allocated to A?
2. If no then how to achieve the scenario when "fix amount of memory is assigned to a process that other process can not use"?

**EDIT**

Is it possible to lock physical memory for process? Or only VM can be locked so that no other process can access it?

There is one multimedia application that must remain alive and can use maximum system resource in terms of memory, I need to achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the concrete scenario? What kind of application are you using and asking the question for? **Why do you ask?**

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The scenario is, for example on system with 1 GB RAM, I want to allocate ~700 MB of memory that can exclusively be used by that process only. For all the other processes remaining ~300 MB can be used.

Comment: But that does not tell about the application or program you are running. In general your question is much too abstract. I guess that careful use of `ulimit`, `renice`, `ionice` should be enough

Comment: There is one multimedia application that must remain alive and can use maximum system resource in terms of memory, I need to achieve this.

Comment: You should edit your question, not comment it

Comment: Though i am not getting the exact idea, will check and update.

Answer (score 1):

[Processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) are using [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) (not RAM) so they have a [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). See also [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) (called by `ulimit` shell builtin). Perhaps `RLIMIT_RSS` & `RLIMIT_MEMLOCK` are relevant. Of course, you could limit some *other* process e.g. using `RLIMIT_AS` or `RLIMIT_DATA`, perhaps thru [pam_limits(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/pam_limits.8.html) & [limits.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/limits.conf.5.html)

You could lock some virtual memory into RAM using [mlock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mlock.2.html), this ensures that the RAM is kept for the calling process.

If you want to improve performance, you might also use [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html) & [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html).

See also [ionice(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ionice.1.html) & [renice(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/renice.1.html)

BTW, you might consider using hypervisors like [Xen](http://www.xenproject.org/), they are able to reserve RAM.

At last, you might be wrong in believing that your manual tuning could do better than a carefully configured kernel [scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29).

Comment: `mlock` will prevent memory from being paged to the swap area, In my system i have swap space turned off.

Comment: Not only swap, it prevent memory from being paged out (e.g. to a file). And I believe you should have some swap space (since the overall performance of the system would then be improved)

Comment: Thanks, but i have application in executable form, no source code, Now only thing i can do is externally restrict resource limit.

Comment: I guess that Xen would be appropriate.

Comment: I'm sure that combining the several ideas in my answer is enough for your particular case

Comment: @SD.: you might be able to hook some library calls fairly easily if the binary you have is dynamically linked.  Set `LD_PRELOAD` to the path to a library you've made that does extra stuff on top of `malloc`, or something.  There's a lot you can do, but nothing super-useful comes to mind right away.

Answer (score 0):

What other processes will run on the same system, and what kind of thing do you want to happen if the other multimedia program needs memory that other processes are using?

You could weight the multimedia process so the OOM killer only picks it as a last choice after every other non-essential process.  You might see a dropped frame if the kernel takes some time killing something to free up memory.

[According to this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html), adjust the oom-killer weight of a process by writing to `/proc/pid/oom_adj`.  e.g. with

```
echo -17 > /proc/2592/oom_adj
```