# How to isolate memory and cpu for a process which no other process can use?

Tags: linux, docker, virtual-machine

We have a host in which several different processes run, and on this host, we have deployed our website. However, when the other processes start to take too much memory, the linux OOM killer starts killing processes and it kills our web server as well. Is there any way to ensure certain memory and cpu will always be available to a certain process and the linux OOM killer won't kill that process?

Basically what can we do to ensure that the website always stays up, whatever be the number of processes on the host?

[Allocate memory to a process that other process can not use in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731636/allocate-memory-to-a-process-that-other-process-can-not-use-in-linux)
In this page, it is said, that using hypervisors can be one solution, is that the recommended way to handle such problems? Also, can docker help here?

Comment: How do you manage your service? If you server has systemd support, then I would start your website service via a systemd service and let systemd handle the restart after the OOM killer striked.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the OOM killer more lenient or completely disable it for a given process through `/proc/[pid]/oom_score_adj`.

[The documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/next/filesystems/proc.html) explains:

> The value of `/proc/<pid>/oom_score_adj` is added to the badness score before it is used to determine which task to kill. Acceptable values range from -1000 (`OOM_SCORE_ADJ_MIN`) to +1000 (`OOM_SCORE_ADJ_MAX`). This allows userspace to polarize the preference for oom killing either by always preferring a certain task or completely disabling it. **The lowest possible value, -1000, is equivalent to disabling oom killing entirely for that task since it will always report a badness score of 0.**

So in your case, after starting the process, find its PID and do:

```
echo -1000 | sudo tee /proc/[PID]/oom_score_adj
```

The `sudo tee` is because you need higher privileges to modify `oom_score_adj`, namely `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE`.

> Also, can docker help here?

Not really, the problem needs to be solved in the host anyway. Putting things inside a container or PID/user namespaces does not affect the underlying issue.

---

Side note: if memory runs low, at some point the kernel will *have to* kill something, and if it's not your process it may very well be some other important system component that will make things crash in unexpected ways. If that does not work, the kernel could even decide to panic. Therefore, disabling the OOM killer for an important process may help, but is not a general definitive solution: it depends on the situation.

Comment: My process is not the culprit, rather other processes running on that host sometimes take too much memory. Basically this host is used by many people for different needs.

Comment: @In78 Ok, that's fair enough. You could be in a situation where the system has 8G RAM, your process is using 5G and another one uses 3G, but you would like the second one to be killed.

Comment: Yeah basically I want my process to have higher priority. I was also thinking whether a VM can be allotted to each user on that host so that their processes will only run in their VM and not on bare metal. In this way, the processes of one user will not interfere with another.

Comment: @In78 yeah, that is definitely another (more robust) solution. Cgroups are also another possibility to limit memory.